# DateTimeZone Error Apache2 Log

Tags: php, apache, timezone, apache2

When I try to enter the site a white page appears. Anyway
I checked all files and everything look good.
Also, my server has a time zone.
I don't know what I should do?

```
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.190385 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.193439 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID '' is invalid in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 92
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.193476 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: object::$default_timezone in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93
[Mon May 21 21:06:21.193603 2018] [:error] [pid 13340] [client 89.64.24.10:19041] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone () in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php:93\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php(93): DateTimeZone->__construct('')\n#1 /var/www/html/frontend/htdocs/index.php(4): include('/var/www/html/f...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/frontend/lib/common.php on line 93
```

time zone line 92-93-94-95 (common.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set($CFG->default_timezone);
$dtz = new DateTimeZone($CFG->default_timezone);
$dtz1 = new DateTime('now', $dtz);
$CFG->timezone_offset = $dtz->getOffset($dtz1);
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear to me. `$CFG->default_timezone` is undefined

Comment: but İ did it , default_timezone is defined. @FelippeDuarte

Comment: debug or print this value $CFG->default_timezone and check

Answer (score 0):

The `default_timezone` property in the `$CFG` object does not exist.

Perhaps $CFG is an array and not an object? Try `$CFG['default_timezone']` instead of `$CFG->default_timezone`.

Also, try `var_dump($CFG);` to show the type and value.